# Split string array into smaller arrays

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, string

I've looked around but can't find anything that has helped me. I have the following issue - I have a string array that contains:

[0] = "2.4 kWh @ 105.00 c/kWh"

where [0] is the index of the array. I need to split it by a space, so that I can have several smaller arrays. So it should look like:

```
[0] will contain 2.4
[1] will contain kWh
[2] will contain @
[3] will contain 105.00
[4] will contain c/mWh
```

I've tried several solutions but none works. Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: @kviiri Good point. I thought I'm in PHP :)

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you a two dimensional array (array of string arrays):

```
var newArr = strArr.Select(s => s.Split(' ').ToArray()).ToArray();
```

for example:

```
string[] strArr = new string[] { "2.4 kWh @ 105.00 c/kWh", "Hello, world" };

var newArr = strArr.Select(s => s.Split(' ').ToArray()).ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < newArr.Length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < newArr[i].Length; j++)
        Console.WriteLine(newArr[i][j]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}

//  2.4
//  c/kWh
//  @
//  105.00
//  kWh
//
//  Hello,
//  world
```

Comment: Thanks so much, guys. This gives me the data I need, however, there is another problem. We're using foreach statements, which is fine, however, I will need to use some kind of for loop, as I need the index for these items. They need to be specifically placed somewhere, so I cannot just iterate through them to show their values. Any suggestions from you guys?

Comment: Guys, thanks so much. Your suggestions worked. I am so happy!

Have a great day further!

Answer (score 3):

[Reference](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split)

```
string s = "2.4 kWh @ 105.00 c/kWh";
string[] words = s.Split(new char [] {' '});  // Split string on spaces.
foreach (string word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

**Then you can get the console output as**

```
2.4
kWh
@
105.00
c/mWh
```

Answer (score 1):

We'll use `string[] strings = new[] { "2.4 kWh @ 105.00 c/kWh", "this is a test" };` as an example of your array.

This is how you can put it all into one array. I've kept it as an `IEnumerable<T>` to keep that benefit, but feel free to append `.ToArray()`.

```
public IEnumerable<string> SplitAll(IEnumerable<string> collection)
{
    return collection.SelectMany(c => c.Split(' '));
}
```

Here, this would evaluate to `{ "2.4", "kWh", "@", "105.00", "c/kWh", "this", "is", "a", "test" }`.

Or if I'm misunderstanding you and you actually do want an array of arrays,

```
public IEnumerable<string[]> SplitAll(IEnumerable<string> collection)
{
    return collection.Select(c => c.Split(' '));
}
```

Here,  `{ { "2.4", "kWh", "@", "105.00", "c/kWh" }, { "this", "is", "a", "test" } }`.

Or if I'm totally misunderstanding you and you just want to split the one string, that's even easier, and I've already shown it, but you can use [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx).